# p-laplacian and differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, p-laplacian

We have the operator: $$\Phi_p(x)= x\lvert x \rvert^{p-2}$$
as I think is the one-dimensional p-laplacian.
We also have the differential equation :

$$ (\Phi_p(x'(t)))'+\lambda \Phi_p (x(t)) = 0$$

where ' mean $\frac{d}{dt}$.
I need to solve the equation for p =2 , that give me : $$\Phi_2(x'(t)))' +\lambda x = 0  $$

That I read :
$$\Phi'_2(\frac{dx}{dt}) \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\lambda x$$

I need to solve for $\lambda$, but honestly , I don't know where to start.

Does somoene have a hint on how to solve this equation ?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\Phi_2(x) = x$ so $(\Phi_2(x^\prime))^\prime = (x^\prime)^\prime$. Thus, you need to solve
$$
x^{\prime\prime} = -\lambda x
$$
Here, $\prime$ is for $\frac{d}{dt}$. This is a basic second order ODE. There are many resources to se how to solve it.
For instance, Paul's online notes (problem 4) has a solution with $\lambda =16$. See [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ComplexRoots.aspx). The solution on the real line depends whether $-\lambda$ has real or complex roots.

Comment: Thank  @Quoka. The only thing I dont understand is , if ′ is for $\frac{d}{dt}$, why $ \frac{d}{dt}\Phi_2(x)=1$. If we said that $\Phi_2(x) =x$.

Comment: @Doodger24 sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: @I understand now , thanks a lot !